# Getting TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' when trying to use subprocess

Tags: python

I'm new to python so forgive me if I make any stupid errors. I've been trying to figure out how to pass a command to cmd.exe for about an hour now and have encountered an error every time. Recently I've gotten this error: TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
#defines a function to run BDP command with subprocess
def runcommand(command):
    """Runs command in cmd.exe"""
    import subprocess
    cmd = command
    returned_value = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)  
    # returns the exit code in unix
    print('returned value:', returned_value)

#defines a messagebox function to tell user what file to get
def messagebox(displayinfo):
    """Presents a messagebox telling the user to select a file"""
    from tkinter import messagebox
    messagebox.showinfo(message = displayinfo)

#Sets home to users home path eg C:/users/hsun2
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
from tkinter import filedialog

#asks user for location of bfc file
messagebox('Select the bfc.nii.gz file')
bfcfile = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(bfcfile)

#asks user for location of DTI.nii files
messagebox('Select your DTI.nii file')
dtinii = filedialog.askopenfilename()

#asks user for location of bval file
messagebox('Select bval file')
bvalfile = filedialog.askopenfilename()

#asks user for bvec file
messagebox('Select bvec file')
bvecfile = filedialog.askopenfilename()

output = r"'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile 
+ " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile 
+ " -b " + bvecfile

#print(output)

#runs bdp command with user input
#output = runcommand("'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile +
#" --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile +
#" -b " + bvecfile)
```

Returns

```
C:/Users/hsun2/Desktop/localBDP/MTS/testpy/MTS126028/BrainSuite/sagT1MPRAGE_we_normal.bfc.nii.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bdpcommandtest.py", line 44, in <module>
    + " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Your indent is wrong.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve], including the actual exception, with its traceback, that will tell you (or at least us) exactly which line is causing that error.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using `shell=True` and a command line instead of `shell=False` and a list of arguments? You don't seem to be using any shell features. And meanwhile, you _are_ being forced to work around the shell by quoting the command name, and may well be failing to quote arguments that need to be quoted, and all of that is an unnecessary problem.

Comment: @abarnert C:/Users/hsun2/Desktop/localBDP/MTS/testpy/MTS126028/BrainSuite/sagT1MPRAGE_we_normal.bfc.nii.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bdpcommandtest.py", line 44, in <module>
    + " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + str(dtinii) + " -g " + str(bvalfile)
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Edit that into the question, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: Meanwhile, your code as posted obviously doesn't produce that error, because it generates a `SyntaxError` on that `runs bdp command with user input` line before it can even start running your code. That may seem nitpicky, but since your actual problem is likely something similarly trivial (like maybe you accidentally closed the parentheses after `bfcfile` or left out a `+` somewhere or… who knows), you have to paste exactly what you have to debug your problem.

Comment: Plus, your code as posted has the hanging `+` at the end of each line, but your exception has it at the start, and your code as posted doesn't have all those unnecessary `str` calls, but your exception does. Which means your actual code is even farther from the code you posted, and even more impossible to debug.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, I'm really new to this. I think I mixed it up. I edited it so both should be correct now. Still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as originally posted was legal, because the long string concatenation expression was inside parentheses, and parentheses automatically allow you continue an expression onto the next line:

```
output = runcommand("'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile +
" --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile +
" -b " + bvecfile)
```

However, when you take the exact same expression outside of parentheses, it's no longer valid:

```
command = "'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile +
" --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile +
" -b " + bvecfile
```

… because now it's three separate expressions, one on each line. And the first one raises a `SyntaxError`, because it ends with a `+` with no right arguments.

And if you move the hanging `+` to the next line, as in your final posted code:

```
command = "'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile
+ " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile
+ " -b " + bvecfile
```

… now it's syntactically valid, but nonsensical—the first line is fine, but the second line is trying to apply the unary `+` operator to a string, so you get a `TypeError`.

---

You can fix this by putting the expression back inside parentheses:

```
command = ("'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile
+ " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile
+ " -b " + bvecfile)
```

… or by using backslash continuation:

```
command = "'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile \
+ " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile \
+ " -b " + bvecfile
```

Although really, even though indentation isn't meaningful to Python inside expressions the way it is in statements, it is meaningful to human readers, so you should try to make it more readable, maybe something like this:

```
command = (
    "'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile
    + " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii
    + " -g " + bvalfile
    + " -b " + bvecfile
)
```

---

However, the *real* fix here should be not using string concatenation in the first place. You're not using the shell here, and in fact you're fighting against it, and not entirely successfully. So just use a list of arguments and don't ask for the shell, and now we don't have to worry about quoting or spacing or getting string concatenation right:

```
command = [
    r"C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe", bfcfile,
    "--FRT", "--FRACT", "--tensor", "-nii", dtinii,
    "-g", bvalfile, "-b", bvecfile
]
```

And now, call it without `shell=True`:

```
returned_value = subprocess.call(command)
```

---

As a side note, notice that I added an `r` before the path to the program. A `\b` in a Python string literal doesn't mean a backslash and a letter b, it means a `^H` backspace character. When using Windows pathnames with backslashes as literal values in your source code, always either escape them, or use a raw `r` prefix.

Also, I'm not sure why you added the `str(…)` calls all over your code to things that are already strings, but… that's never going to help anything, it just makes things harder to read, so I left them out, as in your original version.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been beyond helpful to a python newbie. Sorry for all my stackoverflow errors lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of `output` should have the line continuation character \ at the end of each line. Your previous code did not need it because it was enclosed in parentheses. Make sure the \ is the very last visible character on the line, what you are actually doing is "escaping" the newline which follows.  The calls to `str()` are unnecessary.

```
output = r"'C:\Program Files\BrainSuite18a\bdp\bdp.exe' " + bfcfile \
+ " --FRT --FRACT --tensor --nii " + dtinii + " -g " + bvalfile \
+ " -b " + bvecfile
```

You should use a *raw string* (that's the `r".."`) for Windows paths using a \ (or use \\ or /) for a directory separator.  In your path `\b` gets translated to a backspace (\x08) without it.